# How to read the value of the cookie in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm using cookie-parser module.
And I set a cookie like this:

```
res.cookie('user', 'someValue', {maxAge: 10800});
```

the question here is how I print the value of the cookie?
I tried :

```
console.log('cookie: ' + req.cookies);
console.log('cookie: ' + req.cookies.user);
console.log('cookie: ' + res.cookie('user'));
```

but all I received is just [Object] or undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't stringify the object you'll get to see more:

```
console.log('cookie: ', req.cookies); // comma instead of `+`
```